# I cant install truffle framework

Tags: solidity, truffle

Hello guy I'm trying to install truffle by running

```
npm install -g truffle
```

but it keeps showing warnings and errors that looks like this [image]

```
`npm ERR! code EEXISTnpm ERR! path C:\Users\Taha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.jsnpm ERR! dest C:\Users\Taha\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.cmdnpm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\Taha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js' -> 'C:\Users\Taha\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.cmd'npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Taha\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.cmdnpm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npmnpm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:npm ERR!     C:\Users\Taha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-26T16_37_18_617Z-debug.log`
```

i also tried to run `npm install truffle -save-dev` but also not working

Can anybody explain to me why I'm getting this errors and i cant run truffle framework ?
and if my command is wrong can anybody give me a command that works please

Answer (score 0):

Truffle has been installed on your system. Its a common error while installing truffle.
Just try running

```
 truffle --version
```

If this does not give you the version please tell me, We will find some other solutions.

Comment: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Taha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
} got this when i run truffle --version

Comment: check if you have correctly installed node.js in your system with this command

Comment: node --version . If node is not installed properly please install in correctly.

Comment: my node version is v16.14.2